# Embed Javafx in html

Tags: java, javascript, html, javafx

I would like to simply ask if it is possible to embed a javafx application inside an html file. And if it is possible then I would like to know how to do this. I am open to using javascript etc. if it is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking about including JavaFX script inline in an HTML file, I do not think that's possible.

However, if you just want to have a JavaFX widget on a web page, then yes. Use something like this:

```
    <script src="http://dl.javafx.com/dtfx.js"></script>
    <script>
        javafx(
        {
            archive: "HelloApplet.jar",
            draggable: true,
            width: 150,
            height: 100,
            code: "hello.HelloApplet",
            name: "Wiki"
        }
    );
    </script>
```

Code from [Planet JFX](http://jfx.wikia.com/wiki/Applet_Example)